# Python: Check if list item contains item inside with specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Have list: `[{"id":19308,"key":[866]},{"id":19307,"key":[866]}]`

Need to verify if `"id":19307` is in list

Tried like:
`if any(i['id'] == id in i for i in response): return True`
but condition is not true
where is mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do this (with `label` set to `19307`):

```
any(i['id'] == label for i in response)
```

Also, I renamed `id` as `label` because `id` is already a built-in in python, that could lead to confusion. This was not the cause of the error if you did `id = 19307` previously, but it is not recommended to rename a built-in.

The error was the extraneous `in i`. I must own I am not sure about what this did (maybe tried to check if the result of `i['id'] == id` was in `i`, e.g. to check if `True`, or `False` was in `i`)

Comment: thx, your version and version @Phuong Nguyen also worked. What diffrence in check like `any([item['id'] == id for item in response])` and `any(i['id'] == label for i in response)` ? Are there any differences in performance of memory usage?

Comment: No difference that I know of, in terms of performance or memory usage. But it's definitely a better practice to not redefine a built-in like `id` and use another name (`label` is just a random example). Also, you'd certainly better not put your `any()` test in an `if` that will only lead to `return True`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
any([item['id'] == id for item in response])
```